# How to merge 2 or more lines text into 1 line with condition in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to read the Sent file of Thunderbird Mozilla into R.
Sometimes 2 or more lines have to be put together in 1 line.
Those are lines that end with a ',' comma
For example:

```
From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>
Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar
To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl,
 griepje@zeenit.nl, Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com,
 pico11@zeenit.nl
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100
```

After merging:

```
From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>
Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar
To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl, griepje@zeenit.nl, Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com,  pico11@zeenit.nl
Message-ID: <56EFF455.5000006@zeenit.nl>
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100
```

Comment: Added regex tag, readLines, then use regex, replace "comma new line" with "comma".

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't just rely on the commas. Using `grep` you could identify the line with `To:` tag and paste all the lines until the line with the following tag `Message-ID:/Date:`.

```
cleanHeader <- function(x) {
  line.to <- grep("^To", header)
  line.next <- grep("^Date|^Mess", header)[1]
  new.to <- paste(header[line.to:(line.next - 1)], collapse="")
  c(header[1:(line.to - 1)], new.to, header[line.next:length(header)])
}
```

### Result

```
cleanHeader(header1)  
[1] "From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>"
[2] "Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar"
[3] "To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl, griepje@zeenit.nl, 
     Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com, pico11@zeenit.nl"
[4] "Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100"                                                   

cleanHeader(header2)
[1] "From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>"                                                  
[2] "Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar"
[3] "To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl, griepje@zeenit.nl, 
     Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com,  pico11@zeenit.nl"
[4] "Message-ID: <56EFF455.5000006@zeenit.nl>"
[5] "Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100"
```

---

*Data:*

```
tmp <- tempfile()

cat("From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>
Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar
To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl,
 griepje@zeenit.nl, Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com,
 pico11@zeenit.nl
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100", file=tmp, sep="\n")

header1 <- readLines(tmp)

cat("From: Frans  <frans@zeenit.nl>
Subject: volledig overzicht beschikbaar
To: aldjan@gmail.com, clen@zeenit.nl, pinge1@zeenit.nl, griepje@zeenit.nl, Jowialj@live.com, pelicaan@hotmail.com,  pico11@zeenit.nl
Message-ID: <56EFF455.5000006@zeenit.nl>
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 14:17:09 +0100", file=tmp, sep="\n")

header2 <- readLines(tmp)
```